# Logout users if browser/tab gets closed and user didn't logoff orderly

Tags: php

I managed to get the query to update the database after 15 min of inactivity and log out the user. but when the user logs in and closes the browser, the only time they will be logged out is next time the go on the website. How can i do it so that even if they close the browser, the database still gets updated somehow?

```
// log out the user after 60 seconds of inactivity
    if (isset($_SESSION['timestamp'])) {
        $elapsed_time = time() - $_SESSION['timestamp'];
        if ($elapsed_time >= 900) {
            mysql_query("UPDATE `users` SET `status` = '0' WHERE `user_id` = '$session_user_id'");
            session_destroy();
            header('Location:index.php');
        }
    }
    $_SESSION['timestamp'] = time();
```

at this point, if the user logs in and closes the browser, they will appear logged in forever

Comment: you can't reliably detect when a tab/window is closed. It's simply not possible. Run a scheduled job on your system to log out anyone who's been idle for longer than a set period and get on with more important things.

Comment: Instead of using a `status` field you should consider using a `last_active` field. You can [infer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inference) inactivity based on when the user's last action occurred. Keeping track of a user's status is inherently unreliable on a state-less system like the internet.

Comment: I use the status to determine whether the user should have a green or a red dot next to their user name. how can i achieve that using last_active? can you give me an example code?

Comment: @Bamba It is not complicated. If the user's last action was less than 10 minutes ago then they are active; between 10-20 minutes they are idle; more than 20 minutes then they are offline. These are just arbitrary numbers that you can set.

Comment: yea but i am asking what happens if the close the browser, how does any query is being checked and sent to the database?

Answer (score 1):

Marc B suggests you should "Run a scheduled job on your system to log out anyone who's been idle for longer than a set period" - however this is no different when what the garbage collection in the session handler does.

I agree with Sverri that you shouldn't use a separate state variable when you need to track the last activity of the user anyway.

If it were me I'd implement the logic at the session manager tier - and refuse to load expired sessions.

Answer (score 0):

you can update the activity  of the user and just use the last timestamp. you can also run a worker that will update it

Comment: Certainly there's no point in holding the same information in 2 separate fields in the database (it breaks the rules of normalization anyway). But there's no need to *update* the time of the last activity - the session manager does that anyway.

Answer (score 0):

**Execute an onUnload script**

One option is to execute a JavaScript each time unloads a document:

```
<body onunload="ajaxDoLogoff()">
```

with

```
function ajaxDoLogoff() {

   xmlhttp.open( "GET", "performLogoff.php", false );
   xmlhttp.send();

}
```

**Track user's activity and invalidate all inactive users**

Or add a field `lastActivity INT(11)` to the user `table` which holds the unix timestamp.

If **user does a login** or a **logged in user returns**, keep track of his activity:

```
$query = 'UPDATE `users` '
       . '   SET `status`         = "1",  '
       . '       `lastActivity`   = "' . $time() . '" '
       . ' WHERE ( `userID`       = "' . $userID . '" ) '
       ;

mysql_query( $query );
```

Sufficiently often, do the cleanup of outdated sessions:

```
$deadSessionTimestamp = time() - $thresholdInSeconds;

$query = 'UPDATE `users` '
       . '   SET `status` = "0" '
       . ' WHERE ( `lastActivity` < "' . $deadSessionTimestamp . '" ) '
       ;

mysql_query( $query );
```

Side effect: The application now tracks the last activity of each user.

**Bonus: Show the last activity date/time upon a login operation**

Using this query

```
$query = 'SELECT `lastActivity ` '
       . ' WHERE ( `userID` = "' . $userID . '" ) '
       ;
```

and if a user submits userID/password, you might tell him the date/time of his last-time login.

Comment: wouldn't this only work as log as you are on the website? and im not too sure how to use the javascript part

Comment: @Bamba No this logs off each user with outdated activity state. You just need to execute the lower query, often enough. Simplest location would be index.php, if each query comes in through this script. Note, that there may exist better scripts, which execute the lower query less often. Actually, you can even execute the lower script using a CRON job too.

Comment: i did this mysql_query("UPDATE `users` SET `status` = '1' WHERE `user_id` = '".$session_user_id."'  AND `lastActivity` = '" . timestamp() . ' ""); and it tells me undefined timestamp()

Comment: @Bamba Sorry, my fault. Just use time(). Code updated.

Comment: okay just did that and when i log in i see 0 under lastActivity on the db table.. i log out still 0

Comment: @Bamba Oh, sorry, still a problem in my code. Fixed it: See the changed upper query.

Comment: okay so that makes the status and the lastActivity change, how can i make it logout after x minutes if the browser is closed? the only way it will close now is if you are on the website and dont touch it for x minutes

Comment: E.g. execute the one but last script/query each time you execute index.php

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47534/discussion-between-bamba-and-steap)